# Dataflow Gen 2 - Microsoft Power BI REST API

Tags: microsoft-fabric

I was wondering if anyone has had luck building a Fabric Gen 2 Dataflow to pull the Power BI Rest APIs?  I'm curious on the token exchange process, and navigating the token expiring.  Thank you!